# Transforming private key into address

Tags: address, development, private-key, public-key

[How do I get to the value in the 'scriptPubKey' part of the transaction ?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36634/how-do-i-get-to-the-value-in-the-scriptpubkey-part-of-the-transaction) shows a great example of going from address to scriptPubKey.

I'd like to do something similar: go from private key (ECDSA) to address.  How do I do that? References to libs or code, as in the above question, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From a privatekey (ECC, 32Byte) to an P2PKH address:

1. Ensure the private key is a valid ECC privat key ([libsecp256k1 function](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1/blob/master/include/secp256k1.h#L475))
2. Calculate the public key from the private key (complex math. function, use a library)
3. Calculate the RIPEMD160 hash (aka Hash160) from the public key
4. Do a base58check encoding of the hash160 with a prefix byte 0x00 (for mainnet) or 0x6f for testnet

C code to explore:
https://github.com/libbtc/libbtc/blob/3331ec47ca4ad33e8f2e46e6f01dfbeae090c53d/src/toolfunc.c#L22

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help, assuming you're fine with PHP code.

https://github.com/peterscott78/synala/blob/master/data/lib/bip32.php#L348